# How to read a large file with node.js, and pull for changes constantly

Tags: javascript, node.js, readline, fs

I want to read a large file (ideally starting from the end), and pull for changes.

In ruby for instance, it would be easy.

- `log_file.seek(0, IO::SEEK_END)` to start at the end of the file
- call `log_file.each_line { |log| ... }` in a loop: when new lines are added, they are read.

In node.js, I can't manage to do it...

The big file part can be managed with something like this:

```
var rl = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: require('fs').createReadStream("Client.txt")
});

rl.on('line', function (line) {
  console.log('Line from file:', line);
});
```

so that it doesnt read the whole file at once.

But how to do that in a loop? This will close the file when it gets to the end... And if I have the `rl.on('line' ...)` part in a loop, it would continuously add new listeners...

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: If the file is just appended to, I would use `fs.stat()` to just check the filesize, and only read from the file if the size changes.

Comment: Oh, and there's also `fs.watchFile()` that actually watches the file for changes automagically for you-

Comment: Right, but all you get is the info that the file has changed (and stats), and then you need to reopen the file, and start reading from the right place. It could be expensive for a log file that receives changes pretty often. Correct? No way to keep the file open, and then read from the current cursor position when the file changes?

Comment: a log file will only change at the end, so if you know the old size and the new size, then just knowing it changed from watch() or watchFile() and how big it is will be enough to open() the file towards the end. you can't use readline, but it's not that hard to breakup a small sub-file-portion in RAM...

Comment: Right, seems like a good solution. I found this module: https://github.com/adam-p/text-file-follower. I think it pretty much does what you guys are suggesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best module I found to do that is [text follower](https://github.com/adam-p/text-file-follower).

It's based on `fs.watchFile` (through watchit).

Tested it on Windows and OSX.